# regex for ls -ld

Tags: regex, shell, ls

I have a directory consists of different types of files, including directory and individual files with similar names - so pattern must be very exact.

I need to use **ls -ld** to just to extract directories, and look for particular patterned directory. After getting this, I need to find out what that particular **string_w_pattern** is to store as variable.

I am running this in sh.

Known string is **my_dir** and **my_prop_dir**

```
/my_dir/string_w_pattern/my_prop_dir
```

**string_w_pattern** consists of 2-3 characters in capital letters with one number always comes on the second place.

I have tried following but getting more than two output since names for **string_w_pattern** are similar.

```
ls -ld /my_dir/[A-Z]*[A-Z0-9]\/my_prop_dir
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell uses glob expression syntax here, not regular expresssion. The `*` will expand like the regex `.*`. Also, drop the `\` masking your `/`. Try this:

```
ls -ld /my_dir/[A-Z][A-Z][0-9]/my_prop_dir /my_dir/[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9]/my_prop_dir
```

To filter out the desired string from the result, use sed or cut.